# How to let user type only allow charaters in UITextfield?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

For now, my input recieved input with format like this `CCXXXXXXXXXX` ( C = character, X = Numeric ).

I want to let user can type only follow format

**example**

| user input | result on textfield |
| --- | --- |
| `AA1234` | AA1234 |
| `A2` | A |
| `AAA` | AA |
| `AA12345A` | AA12345 |

I mean if user type not follow format, character will not type on textfield

Comment: show us the code you have done so far. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a regular expression.

I think `"[A-Z]{0,1}+[A-Z]{0,1}+[0-9]*"` is the format you want. Each time a letter is entered in the textField, it checks for formatting.

If it doesn't fit the format, the letter is deleted. 
That's why it doesn't seem to be entered.

```swift
@IBOutlet weak var inputTextField: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
  inputTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
}

func checkFormat(text: String?) -> Bool {
  guard text != nil else { return false }

 let textRegEx = "[A-Z]{0,1}+[A-Z]{0,1}+[0-9]*"
  let pred = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", textRegEx)
  return pred.evaluate(with: text)
}

@objc func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {
  if !checkFormat(text: textField.text) {
    textField.deleteBackward()
  }
}
```

Comment: I ever use this way too but it will have problem when user copy/pasted it will delete only last character.

Comment: @Heily Thank you for your reply, I made the function like u but move it to function shouldChangeCharacterIn. It working!! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can set delegate for your textfield

```
class SampleViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var myTextfield: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        myTextfield.delegate = self
    }
}
```

and then check for typed character and verify what characters should be permitted or not.

```
extension SampleViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {

    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    
        // Check for backspace
        if let char = string.cString(using: String.Encoding.utf8) {
            let isBackSpace = strcmp(char, "\\b")
            if (isBackSpace == -92) {
                return true
            }
        }
    
        if( range.location < 2 ) {
            return Character(string).isLetter ? true : false
        } else {
            return Character(string).isNumber ? true : false
        }
    }
}
```

This should solve your problem